# rsync hardlink attempt copies

Tags: rsync, synchronization, hard-link

I've tried setting up a script to hardlink my files to my box.com account (as it's a backup of my music library). As I want to run it automatically to sync my music across several devices, I wanted to use rsync as I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.4 (if anyone cares).

The script I came up with however only copies the files instead of hardlinking them (the available disc space lowers when I start the script). What I'm trying to achieve is the box.com app syncing something outside its actual folder.

This is the script I use:

```
rsync -azluPhmt --progress --link-dest=./iTunes ./iTunes/Users/admin/Box.com/iTunes --delete-during --exclude="*Album Artwork*"
```

Comment: Oh, I just had to use absolute paths. now this one works:

`rsync -azluPhmt --progress --link-dest=/Users/admin/Music/iTunes /Users/admin/Music/iTunes/  /Users/admin/Box.com/iTunes --delete-during --exclude="*Album Artwork*"`

Comment: Note that `-P` makes `--progress` redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`rsync` man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) section for `--link-dest=DIR`,

> If *DIR* is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.

I am guessing that you assumed it would be relative to the current working directory. You probably meant to write:

```
rsync -azluPhmt --progress --link-dest="$PWD/iTunes" …
```